# How to prevent EF-Linq from generating a different query for variables versus constants?

Tags: performance, linq, entity-framework, query-optimization

I have a Linq-query that returns in LinqPad in approximately a minute (the first time) using hard integer-values.
However, when I turn those hard integer-values into local variables, it takes forever (more than 20 minutes).

My basic questions are:

- Why/how does would a different SQL-query cause this much delay?
- Can I prevent this different SQL-query?

In my trying to solve this (see underneath), I ran into these questions:

- how can I use `DefaultQueryPlanCachingSetting` or `EnablePlanCaching`?
- how can I suppress/prevent query-compilation/optimization ?
- how do I verify if I am using EF5?

The [query-difference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5922207/ef-4-1-why-does-turning-a-constant-into-a-variable-result-in-extra-sub-query) seems to be already noticed, and the [*why* is explained](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5923157) in an answer to that question.  I also have this query-difference where I see an extra sub-SELECT (and some extra JOINs).  And the query uses parameters (`[Extent6].[SomeThingId] = @p__linq__0`) in stead of hard integer-values (`4 = [Extent6].[SomeThingId]`)

However, I am not sure why this would be a problem, and how I can prevent it.
(I understand that the answer *may* be easier when providing the query or DB-layout, but this kind of sensitive material, and my question remains the same...)

I was assuming the problem is from some 'optimization' in the compilation/execution-plan when using parameters. I was trying using [this suggestion to turn of the auto-compilation for L2E](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/efdesign/archive/2011/06/30/auto-compiled-linq-queries-entity-framework-june-2011-ctp.aspx):

```
 db.ContextOptions.DefaultQueryPlanCachingSetting = false;
 //(db as IObjectContextAdapter).ObjectContext.DefaultQueryPlanCachingSetting = false;
```

I could not get this to work, so I tried to find out if I could use the also mentioned [`ObjectQuery.EnablePlanCaching = false;`], but I could not find out where/how to use it.  (I can not get my `IQueryable` to cast to an `ObjectQuery`, nor my context.)  Does anybody know how to use `DefaultQueryPlanCachingSetting` or `EnablePlanCaching`?

Another thing I tried was taking the SQL from the constant-value-Linq, and introduce some SQL-variables in there.  That also worked fine, so I tried turning this in a stored procedure, which I could call from EF.  But now the stored procedure also takes very long to run.

I am (also) wondering [if I really have EntityFramework *5*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15816701/which-version-of-entity-framework-is-used-by-my-project). (This is my first project using Linq, EntityFramework and ASP.MVC.)  But I have turned that in a separate question.

**Update**: I changed the 'regular' stored procedure:

```
SELECT ... WHERE @Id  = [Extent6].[SomeThingId] ...
```

into a stored procedure with a dynamic SQL-statement:

```
@sql = 'SELECT ... WHERE ' + CAST(@Id AS VARCHAR) + ' = [Extent6].[SomeThingId] ...';
EXEC (@sql);
```

With this 'dynamic' stored procedure I do get very quick results.  And since the parameters will be reasonably constant (they will probably change between once a day and once a week), I think this lack of optimization/caching is okay for performance.
(However, I dislike putting business logic in a stored procedure.)

Comment: you're probably making the query execute in C# instead - post your query

Comment: I don't think executing in C# is the problem. I think my update concerning the dynamic query in the stored procedure also illustrates that. I am still in doubt if I should just go with this unelegant 'dynamic procedure'.

Answer (score 1):

I found this post by Stuart Leeks about [Entity Framework 5 controlling automatic query compilation](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/stuartleeks/archive/2012/06/12/entity-framework-5-controlling-automatic-query-compilation.aspx).  It mentions that `DefaultQueryPlanCachingSetting` did not make it past the Release Candidate for EF5, and you need to set the `EnablePlanCaching` property on the ObjectSets instead.  It also has a simple example and a suggestion for a handy extension method.  I'll quote Stuart Leeks' example, since 'regular' [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738562.aspx) does not provide one yet. You can check his blog for the extension method.

```
ObjectQuery<Customer> customersNoCache = context.Customers;
customersNoCache.EnablePlanCaching = false;
var query1 = from customer in context.Customers
             where customer.Country == "UK"
             select customer;
```

**Edit:** I actually had to add some more code [to get from a `DbSet` to an `ObjectQuery`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7214212/422877).  In line with previous `Customer`-example this would look like:

```
ObjectContext lObjectContext = ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext;
ObjectQuery<Customer> lDocCatgNoCache = lObjectContext.CreateObjectSet<Customer>();
```

But the generated SQL still contains the parameter-optimization.  My guess would be that  `EnablePlanCaching` only suppresses caching for generating SQL from Linq, and it does not even consider the cache on the SQL-side?

(Unfortunately, I did not have time to reasearch/test any further. I went along with the implemented the 'dynamic' stored procedure, and finished this project.)